# How can I get the scanner working to read 6 numbers on a text file for my dice game simulator?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, ioexception, filereader, dice

I am doing a programming 1 lab, I've been doing well between compilr and stackoverflow, it's really helping me get through debugging some of the code, but this was a complex problem for my difficulty level.  I am doing a dice simulation where on two six sided dice if the dice roll the same number, in a count of 10,000 dice rolls on a random number generator it will count how many doubles of each type were made.  Success
Now my output, I'm having difficulty understanding the Java packages at the loading of the program.  They are just subroutines that comes with the Java 7 right?? Anyways I looked up as much as possible, and got the output to run correctly:

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat; // Needed for Decimal Format
    import java.util.Scanner; //Needed for the Scanner Class
    import java.io.*;
    /**
    * This program writes data to a file
    */
    public class StatsDemo
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    String filename;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");

    System.out.println("This program calculates statistic on a file contain a series of                     number.");
   System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
   filename = keyboard.nextLine();
   FileStats ds = new FileStats(filename);
   FileWriter ts = new FileWriter("Results.txt");
   PrintWriter bs = new PrintWriter(ts);
   bs.println("Mean" + ds.getMean());
   bs.println("Standard Deviation" +ds.getStdDev());
   bs.close();
   }
   }
```

Then here is my imput module for the stats themselves, (it's just a 6 number stat system, it's not difficult, even then my code isn't that perfect)...the problem is I cannot verify the path or get the scanner working correctly in the run-time to even see if my imput is working correctly.  Should I try specifying the path in the output module(which is the runtime), I am not even good at programming yet, but honestly I would just like to get the scanner working to read the 6 numbers in the text file and just run a mean and standard deviation (formulas complete).

```
    //  To calculate the statistics on a file of numbers
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;

    public class FileStats
    {
    String filename = "Numbers.txt";
private double mean;    //the arithmetic average
private double stdDev;  //the standard deviation
String readRow= null;
boolean rowsLeft = true;
BufferedReader reader= null;
FileReader file = null;
int count=0;
int sum = 0;
double variance;

File inputfile = new File ("Numbers.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(filename);
//Constructor calls calculateMean and calculateStdDev methods
//and store the results in the respective instance variables

public FileStats(String filename) throws IOException
{
    mean = calculateMean(filename);
    stdDev = calculateStdDev(filename);
}

//returns the mean
public double getMean() throws IOException
{
    return mean;
}
public double getVariance() throws IOException
{
    return variance;
}
//returns the standard deviation
public double getStdDev() throws IOException
{
    return stdDev;
}

//returns the calculated arithmetic average
public double calculateMean(String filename) throws IOException
{
    //ADD LINES FOR TASK 4
    while(scan.hasNext()){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String words = scan.next();
    double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num3 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num4 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num5 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num6 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num7 = scan.nextDouble();
    double mean = (num1 + num2 + num3+ num4+ num5+ num6)/6;

    reader.close();

}
    return mean;}
//returns the calculated standard deviation
public double getVariance(String filename)
    {
        while(scan.hasNext()){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String words = scan.next();
    double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num3 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num4 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num5 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num6 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num7 = scan.nextDouble();
    double variance = Math.pow(((num1 + num2 + num3+ num4+ num5+ num6)-
    ((num1 + num2 + num3+ num4+ num5+ num6)/6)),2);
        return 0;
    }
    return variance;
    }
public double calculateStdDev(String filename) throws IOException
{
    //ADD LINES FOR TASK 5
    stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance);


    return stdDev;
}
    }
```

Here is the numbers.txt file at the bottom, I just cut and pasted it into the directory (I'm using blueJ).

```
    Numbers.txt
    8.7
    7.9
    3.0
    9.2
    12.6
    10.0
```

Comment: Where is your Numbers.txt file located?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082586/how-to-read-a-text-file-using-scanner-in-java

Comment: I fixed the numbers file.  It's mostly just getting it to read the file, I left the text file in the /dice directory.  I just get errors when it reads the textfile.

Comment: I can take out the dice part of the simulator and just worry about the file imput and output